# Java (ArrayList) : Grouping a list of persons by name

Tags: java, list

I have a list of persons.
The person bean has the following structure :

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    private String occupation;
    /* Getters and setters*/
    /* toString method */
}
```

This list is tored in an `ArrayList<Person>`. 
The problem is that when I print its data, I obtain :

```
Foo, scientist
Foo, teacher
Bar, student
```

I'd like to print it like this :

```
Foo, scientist, teacher
Bar, student
```

So, how can I group the data automatically ?

Thanks.

Comment: Lookup Multimap structure

Comment: rewrite your print method

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "automatically"?

Comment: Thanks for your comment : Well, I'm looking for a clean method/library that can do the job (grouping data by name and then putting its related values side by side) instead of doing loops.

Comment: use `List<String>` for storing occupations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This test case passes for me:

```
package com.sandbox;

import com.google.common.base.Joiner;
import com.google.common.collect.LinkedListMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class SandboxTest {

    @Test
    public void testQuestionInput() {
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
        persons.add(new Person("Foo", "scientist"));
        persons.add(new Person("Foo", "teacher"));
        persons.add(new Person("Bar", "student"));
        String outputString = getOutputString(persons);
        assertEquals("Foo, scientist, teacher\n" +
                "Bar, student\n", outputString);
    }

    private String getOutputString(List<Person> in) {

        Multimap<String, String> map = LinkedListMultimap.create();
        for (Person person : in) {
            map.put(person.name, person.occupation);
        }

        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        Joiner joiner = Joiner.on(", ");
        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
            buf.append(key).append(", ").append(joiner.join(map.get(key))).append("\n");
        }
        return buf.toString();
    }

    class Person {

        Person(String name, String occupation) {
            this.name = name;
            this.occupation = occupation;
        }

        private String name;
        private String occupation;
    /* Getters and setters*/
    /* toString method */
    }

}
```

It takes the list of Persons and passes them into a Multimap.  [The Multimap comes from the Google guava library.](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

But, you might want to use maurocchi's answer.  it's much cleaner than this.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a clean library, with [emaze-dysfunctional](https://bitbucket.org/rferranti/emaze-dysfunctional) you can write

```
Groups.groupBy(persons, new Pluck<String, Person>(Person.class, "occupation"))
```

obtaining a `Map<String, List<Person>>`.

Comment: In my case, I followed this answer and able to get the groups in console... How to save the arraylists in separate variable... I have 3 groups.

Answer (score 1):

That can be solved in a number of ways. I would probably use Map object, say

```
Map<String, List<String>> occupationsByName = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>(0);
```

I would then loop through the list of persons, using the names as keys to the Map object and initialising the List object whenever I find the key does not previously exist in the Map say,

```
for ( Iterator<String> persons = personsList.iterator(); persons.hasNext() ) {
    String person = persons.next().getName();
    if ( occupationsByName.containsKey( person ) ) {
        occupationsByName.get( person ).add( person.getOccupation() );
    } else {
        occupationsByName.put(person, new ArrayList<String>(0) );
        occupationsByName.get( person ).add( person.getOccupation() );
    }
}
```

I would then add the occupations to the List under the each key, then end by finally printing out the Map.

I have to state that I am making an assumption you know how to use the collection classes, and even if you do not, you can make use of the [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have two `Person` instances that have the same name but different occupation and you consider them to be the same person then you'll need to tell JVM that if two names are equal then those to people are also equal. THat you do by overriding `equals()`

Now the second step is to update the list so that once you try to add a `Person` which already exist in the list (i.e. there is a person that has the same name) then you add the new occupation onto the old one (e.g. by string concatenation).

You don't need any libraries for what you want to do, just need to write complete classes. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grouping data by name. Then use "Comparator".

For eg:

```
Comparator comparator = new TestComparator();
Collections.sort(listTobeSorted, comparator);
```

Now, We will have a sorted list in listTobeSorted.So you can print data as your wish.

//New inner Class

```
public class TestComparator implements Comparator<Person > {

    @Override
    public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
       //To write logic, Please refer the tutorial for Comparator
    }
}
```

I hope this will help your problem.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I assume Persons from your Lists sharing the same name are in fact the same person. If so, you should really rethink about your data organisation.
For instance, you could store, for each person, a list of occupations.

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    private final List<String> occupations = new ArrayList<String>();

    public boolean addOccupation(String occupation) {
        return occupations.add(occupation);
    }
    // getters
}
```

Grouping persons by name is best done by using a Map instead of a List.
You can then write a simple print method as follows:

```
String personsToString(Map<String, Person> personMap) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Person person: personMap.values())
        sb.append(person.getName()).append(", ").append(person.getOccupations()).append("\n");
    return sb.toString();
}
```